# Datetime format help

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, datetime-format

I want only Hr and Min in time format so i did

```
select convert(varchar(20),GETDATE(),108) ===>> output is "12:57:54"
```

but i want only "12:57" this much so how i will do that in sql server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select convert(varchar(5),GETDATE(),108)

Answer (score 0):

`Select cast(DatePart(hour, getdate()) as varchar(2)) + ':' + cast(DatePart(minute, getdate())as varchar(2))`